# How to use Symbol with a defined properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, symbols

as shown below in the code, i am defining some constants. i want to use `Symbol` so that each constant is unique. but when i use, for example, the following line of code:

```
if (isBtnDigitizePolygonClicked.value == true) {
    return polygDigiConstants.CONST_STRING_DIGITIZE;
}
```

the returned value from the aforementioned code is `Symbol('Digitize')`, i expected it to be `Digitize` as stated in this tutorial:https://www.scaler.com/topics/enum-in-javascript/

**tutorial contents**:

```
const Direction = Object.freeze({
  North: Symbol('north'),
  East: Symbol('east'),
  West: Symbol('west'),
  South: Symbol('south'),
})

const Pole = Object.freeze({
  North: Symbol('north'),
  South: Symbol('south'),
})

console.log(Direction.North === Pole.North)

The output of the above code is :

false
```

please let me know how to use `Symbol` correctly with a defined properties

**polygDigiConstants.js**

```
function define(name, value) {
Object.defineProperty(polygDigiConstants, name, {
    value: value,
    enumerable: true,
    writable: false,
});
}

export let polygDigiConstants = {};

define('CONST_STRING_DIGITIZE', Symbol('Digitize'));
define('CONST_STRING_STOP_DIGITIZE', Symbol('Stop'));
define('CONST_STRING_CLEAR_DIGITIZED', Symbol('Clear'));
```

Comment: `the returned value from the aforementioned code is Symbol('Digitize')` what should it be?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What is your question?

Comment: @JaromandaX i expected it to be only `Digitize`

Comment: So you want it to be of type string then? Not symbol?

Comment: `i expected it to be Digitize` ... a String?

Comment: @JaromandaX please have a look again at the question i modified it

Comment: @trincot please have a look again at the question i modified it

Comment: OK, but each time you construct a new symbol, it is a different one. You should only create it once and then keep referencing it. So `const NORTH = Symbol("North")` and then use `NORTH` in your object literals. But after your edit, your question is going in different ways and becomes too broad. Focus on one question?

Comment: you may have modified the question, but you still expect a String where no String belongs ... `polygDigiConstants.CONST_STRING_DIGITIZE.description` will be the string you seek